# How to change installation path for WiXSetup Project

Tags: wix

I have a WixSetup project which is generating the msi file under the project bin folder in file explorer.
Is there any way I can change this and get the msi file to be generated at another preferred location on file explorer?
I tried unloading the project and editing the .wixproj code to achieve this but I keep getting an error (attached a picture below).
I changed the value of the OutputPath and IntermediatePath to my preferred location.

[image]